# Sort a list where each item refers to the items which should come before/after it

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have an unsorted list of objects. These objects have:

- PreviousId
- NextId

I would like to sort the list so that any preceding item has the "NextId" equal to the "PreviousId" that follows it.

E.g.

Item1: PreviousId = 15, NextId = 16

Item2: PreviousId = 16, NextId = 4

Item3: PreviousId = 4, Next Id = 105

Item4: PreviousId = 105, NextId = 40

I can think of a few "messy" ways, but is there a standard way to do something like this? Or a particularly efficient way?

Comment: You'll have to implement custom logic to deal with something like that.  You will have to ensure that every previous has a matching next.  Also, how are you dealing with the start and finish where there is no next item or previous item?

Comment: This seems prone to possibilities that make sorting impossible, like orphans or loops.

Answer (score 2):

If the ids are unique you could create a `Dictionary<PreviousId, object>` from your list to easily find the next item.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, for brevity I'm going to simplify and leave aspects out to cater directly to your intent.

I'm going to assume you have some content in place, but in theory you could modify `Sort` to your requirement.  You could create the following:

```
private Enum Sortable { Previous, Next }
private Enum Sorted { Ascending, Descending }
```

This will provide you a clean clear concise parameter, for your `Sort`.  Now we will assume you have a model for said item:

```
protected void Sort<TKey>(ref List<Model> container, Sorted type, Sortable direction)
{
     Comparison<Model> comparison = null;
     if(type == "Next")
          comparison = (i, j) => i.NextId.CompareTo(j.NextId);
     else { comparison = (i, j) => i.PreviousId.CompareTo(j.PreviousId);

     return comparison
}
```

That would be a way to implement `Sort`.  The implementation is primitive, plus I didn't worry about `Ascending` or `Descending`, so you would need to tailor according.  Once the core of said logic is implemented though, you simply call:

```
Sort<Model>(ref model, type, direction);
```

- `model` would represent your `List<Model>`
- `type` and `direction` the `Enum` for the criteria of your `Sort`.

However, the logic for said implementation is quite a bit more extensive, you could easily get by with `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` if you would like.  Which may save you some time, since your implementation is on the easier side.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I haven't time to write the code, but I'm thinking that once you have found a matching pair, they can be replaced in the list by some kind of aggregate node, since the pair will now have a "next" and a "previous" as a whole (The previous from the first item, the next from the second).

By removing any chained items from the main search you will have less items to search for the remaining links. (Excuse the bad ASCII example)

```
2-3   8-9   1-2   5-6   7-8   4-5


1-3         8-9  5-6   7-8   4-5
(1-2, 2-3)

1-5             8-9  5-6
(1-2, 2-3, 4-5)
```

You will also be able to improve performance by checking for either prev or next on each item. Prev can be added to the start, next to the end.

Answer (score 1):

I've came up with this solution.

```
        public class SampleObject
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Next { get; set; }
        }
        public List<SampleObject> Sort(List<SampleObject> collection)
        {
            var sortedCollection = new List<SampleObject>();

            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                var next = collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(item.Next));

                if (next != null && !sortedCollection.Contains(next) && !sortedCollection.Contains(item))
                {
                    sortedCollection.Add(item);
                    sortedCollection.Add(next);
                }
            }

            return sortedCollection;
        }
```

You can use it like this:

```
var orderedCollection = Sort(yourUnorderedCollection);
```

Answer (score 1):

Most "sorting" algorithims will not work the way you want them to because they rely on being able to compare two random items, and the comparison needs to be reflexive (if a < b then b < a) and transitive (if a < b and b < c then a < c).

In your case it would be simpler just to iterate through the items, optionally putting the data in a new collection in the order you desire:

```
Item current = list[0]; // or whatever starting point you need
List<Item> sorted = new List<Item> {current};

while(true)
{
    Item next = list.SingleOrDefault(i => i.PreviousID == current.NextID);
    if(next == null) // no "next" found - exiting the loop
        break;

    sorted.Add(next);  // add the "next" item to the list
    current = next;    // set the next" item to the "current" item
}
```

Note that there are lots of improvements you can make to this:

- you can put this logic in an `IEnumerator` function and use `yield` statements so you're not creating a separate structure
- You can choose a different "source" data structure (`Dictionary<int, Item>`?) to make the lookups faster
- etc.